Supplier<Stream<T>> from a Stream<T>
How can I create a Supplier from a Stream that is passed as an argument. I know streams can only be consumed once so I thought I would need to "recreate" the stream to be able to supply it. This was my horrible attempt at that. Please help.
public static <T> Supplier<Stream<T>> cache(Stream<T> src) {
        List<T> cachedList = src.toList();
        return cachedList::stream;
}


Well as you said: A stream can only be consumed once. We need to "cache" it if we want to read it multiple times. That said: this sounds like an XY problem (meta.stackexchange.com). What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you need to read the stream multiple times?

@Turing85 It is for a school project where, down the line, I would be retrieving data from a large file (and processing that data) and would like to avoid requerying everytime I needed some data from it. Therefore, I came up with the solution of keeping the data in cache.

Where is the stream coming from initially? I.e. where is the file content transformed in a Stream? It is okay to hold the data in memory. Although I would suggest to convert the stream to a List once and then make all downstream-methods work with the List (the can simply call stream() if they need to).

Also, keep in mind that the file content must fit into memory - with a large file, this might not be feasible.

I initially used the List solution you just described and presented it to my Professor. I'm additionally implementing the Stream solution as per his request. That is why I would like to understand how to make this work.

I recommend you talk to your professor and ask for clarification.

I already did. He asked me to implement this method. I tried it, and would like to understand how it can be well implemented.

I can just repeat myself: I would not implement it this way. I would rather pass a List around than a Stream (a List is more versatile and I can transform it to a Stream with relatively low overhead; a Stream can only be consumed once and depending on what has been "done" with the stream, a transformation to a List might be expensive). So yeah...

according description in question: public static <T> Supplier<Stream<T>> cache(Stream<T> src) { return () -> src; } (but not sure if you really need how it is specified in the question)

In which regard do you consider your solution “horrible”? You could simplify it further to return src.toList()::stream; but then, you’re at the most simple and in a lot of regards most efficient solution. It’s storing all elements, but that’s unavoidable for most use cases. This has been discussed in this question and I’ll close yours as a duplicate of it, but this shouldn’t discourage you from asking such questions. If you think, it doesn’t answer your question (good enough), you may add clarifications and I’ll happily reopen the question…
